# MPD, How to get the name of the current playlist?

Tags: python-2.7, mpd

I am using Python MPD2, is there a way to return the name of the currently selected playlist?

Thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more searching, I finally posted on the musicpd forum

https://forum.musicpd.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=4034

and the response was:

"MPD does not remember of the most recently loaded playlist's name, so there's no way to query it.".

Answer (score 2):

My solution in bash:

```
 CURRENT="$(mpc -f "%file%" playlist | sha512sum )"
 mpc lsplaylist | while read line
 do
 i="$(mpc -f "%file%" playlist $line | sha512sum )"
 if [ "$i" = "$CURRENT" ]; then
    echo "Current playlist is $line"
 fi
 done
```